# Image change in UITableViewCell using Segmented control in another View

Tags: ios, uitableview, uisegmentedcontrol

How to change the IBOutlet image set in `UITableViewCell` using segmented control in another view controller using swift?

**UITableViewCell.swift**:

```
class UserCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet var imageDisplayIcon: UIImageView!
```

**ViewController:**

```
@IBAction func btnClicked(sender: AnyObject) {

    if txtSex.selectedSegmentIndex == 0{

        var imagePicView: UserCell = UserCell()

        imagePicView.imageDisplayIcon.image = UIImage(named: "BoyIcon.png")

        //imageDisplay.image = UIImage(named: "BoyIcon.png")

        print("male")

    }

    if txtSex.selectedSegmentIndex == 1{


        var imagePicView: UserCell = UserCell()

        imagePicView.imageDisplayIcon.image = UIImage(named: "GirlIcon1.png")

        //imageDisplay.image = UIImage(named: "GirlIcon1.png")

        print("female")

    }
```

I get an error saying

```
"fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value."
```

What do I do??

Comment: Is there `tableView` in your `viewController` added?, If yes you need to change image in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you have a `UITableView`

**1. Reload the table data in the action**

```
@IBAction func btnClicked(sender: AnyObject) {
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

**2. Add the image cell in the table data source delegate**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,
    cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let imageName = txtSex.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 ? "BoyIcon.png" : "GirlIcon1.png"

    // Load your cell

    cell.imageDisplayIcon.image = UIImage(named: imageName)

    return cell
}
```

Comment: "@btnClicked" action doesn't happen in the viewController for tableView. so i think the "tableView,reloadData" shows error again.

Comment: @Jenita_Alice4Real if you have the tableView in another viewcontreller you should either call a function of that view controller to reload the table or expose the tableview as public property.

Comment: the view controller where i've written the code is not the view for my table. its another view where the user is to choose between male and female so that the image changes in the cell accordingly.

Comment: If the segment view is in another flow you can store selectedSegmentIndex  and when you go back in your tableview you can reload the data using selectedSegmentIndex value stored

Answer (score 0):

You should reload your `tableview` on your segment's click action after setting cell's image view to make it affected to tableview!!

And you need to manage your `cellforrow` accordingly. In your `cellforrow` datasource method, there should be condition that if selected segment is male then image should be male and vice versa!

Answer (score 0):

You should use 'delegate' between your UserCell and ViewController. That's the best way.